# Network​ Information​ API downlink is never higher than 10 Mbit?

Tags: pagespeed, bandwidth

I try to get some information about the bandwidth of my users. Currently im running NetworkInformation/downlink in Google Tag Manager and pushing it to Google Analytics

https://wicg.github.io/netinfo/#downlink-attribute
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/downlink

Why is there no value higher than 10 Mbit... this looks unrealistic to me? Also having the majority at exactly 10 Mbit downlink seem weird. Is there a limit at 10 Mbit?

[image]

Custom Javascript in GTM looks like this:

```
function () {
 var con = navigator.connection || navigator.mozConnection || navigator.webkitConnetion
 return Number(con.downlink);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/downlink), that's probably because your users are using a Chrome based navigator (or because all navigator implemented this cap since published)
So the speed indicator is capped to a maximum of 10Mpbs